# Slow mysql query full text search tag database

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search, subquery

In the database are ~700k images. Each image has its own tag(s). I want to be able to search images by the tags with a full text search query. The query does exactly what I want but it's very slow. Can someone please help me speed it up, or create another one.

There are indexes on all the id-fields and the name field in the `image_tag` table.

```
SELECT
    image.*
FROM image
INNER JOIN (SELECT image_to_tag.image_id,
             GROUP_CONCAT(image_tag.`name`) AS tags
        FROM image_to_tag
        INNER JOIN image_tag
        ON (image_tag.id = image_to_tag.image_tag_id)
    GROUP BY image_to_tag.image_id) t ON t.image_id = image.id
WHERE MATCH (t.tags) AGAINST ('+justin* +backgrounds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Table: image

```
id | filename 
1  | image1.jpg
2  | image2.jpg
3  | image3.jpg
```

Table: image_to_tag

```
image_id | image_tag_id
1        | 1
1        | 2
2        | 3
2        | 4
```

Table: image_tag

```
id | name
1  | justin bieber
2  | backgrounds
3  | justin timberlake
4  | other backgrounds
```

If I search for "justin background" I want to find images 1 and 2. If I search for "justin bieber background" I want to find image 1.

Results explain query:
[image: explain results]

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) on the query and add the results to your question.

Comment: Just added a picture with the results.

Comment: You are not using actual fulltext index in your query, so it has to scan all tags and try to match them (it is not possible to usefully index the `GROUP_CONCAT()` results). I am not sure if the fulltext match can do "OR", but even if not, you might do a bit of denormalization by concatenating the texts for all tags to some column linked to the image and then fulltext index that. With your current scheme you probably should get all tags matching either "justin" or "backgrounds" so you limit the inner query and only then the `GROUP_CONCAT()` will "precise-filter" the remains.

Answer (score 1):

as I understand work of FT - it must be prepared in advance, so command

```
WHERE MATCH (t.tags) AGAINST ('+justin* +backgrounds*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

against derived table:

```
(SELECT image_to_tag.image_id,
             GROUP_CONCAT(image_tag.`name`) AS tags
        FROM image_to_tag
        INNER JOIN image_tag
        ON (image_tag.id = image_to_tag.image_tag_id)
    GROUP BY image_to_tag.image_id) t
```

must not work - just because when index created no this table present

because query work (not return error from Your description) - MySQL ignore this, but need test with full table structure

also, JOIN with derived table - do not want to use index

Comment: do not check the question date ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should denormalize the tables as such a normalization is leading to too many inner joins and multiple nested select statements.

If normalization is very necessary try maintaining another table. As the number of images is low (~700), you might just skip the *image_to_tag* table.

Otherwise, if the number of tags per image is very low (3-4), try keeping them all in one field separated with some symbol, e.g. `;`, as then they can be easily used by the PHP *explode* function.

Comment: You are miss small "k" after 700 :)